# Azure function deploy error using MSDeploy in Bicep file

Tags: azure-functions, webdeploy, azure-bicep

I'm using a bicep file to deploy Azure resources, among them a FunctionApp and 3 Functions

FunctionApp deployment works fine.

I'm deploying Functions using a zip file created from the "Download app content" button on a previously created FunctionApp and Functions and uploaded on a git repository

This is the bicep content:

```
resource funcAppDeploy 'Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions@2020-12-01' = {
  parent: funcApp
  name: 'MSDeploy'
  properties: {
    packageUri: funcPackageUri
  }
}
```

where funcPackageUri is like this

```
var funcPackageUri = 'https://github.com/<repoorg>/<reponame>/raw/main/<foldername>/funcapp-deploy.zip'
```

I have this error during the deployment:

> {"code":"Failed","message":"ARM-MSDeploy Deploy Failed:
> 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedException: Object of type
> 'package' and path
> 'C:\local\Temp\f5e1b1e4-1a43-4567-95d7-d4ae670fd17f.zip' cannot be
> created. Learn more at:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT.
> ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: The Zip package 'C:\local\Temp\f5e1b1e4-1a43-4567-95d7-d4ae670fd17f.zip' could not be
> loaded. ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Unable to read beyond the
> end of the stream.\r\n at System.IO.BinaryReader.FillBuffer(Int32
> numBytes)\r\n at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadInt32()\r\n at
> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipFile.Load()\r\n at
> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider..ctor(DeploymentProviderContext
> providerContext, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, String path)\r\n
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ZipPackageProvider.GetAttributes(DeploymentAddAttributeContext
> addContext)\r\n at
> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.EnsureValidAttributes()\r\n
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObjectPrivate(DeploymentProviderContext
> providerContext, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject
> sourceObject, String serverVersion)\r\n at
> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentProviderOptions
> providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions)\r\n at
> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(String
> provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions)\r\n at
> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentWellKnownProvider
> provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions)\r\n at
> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.Deploy(String
> deploymentSite, String siteSlotId, Boolean doNotDelete) in
> C:__w\1\s\src\hosting\wdeploy\Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi\AppGalleryPackage.cs:line
> 250\r\n at
> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.d__25.MoveNext()
> in
> C:__w\1\s\src\hosting\wdeploy\Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi\Controllers\DeploymentController.cs:line
> 492'"}

Can you please help me to understand what is wrong?

Comment: Does the runner have access to get that zip to deploy it?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve it only using bicep? Or I would suggest you create a function app using bicep and upload zip content using CLI. If it works for you in this way, community can help you with the detailed steps. @ValeriaN

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar how can I check if the runner has access to get the zip file?

Comment: @Jahnavi, yes I tried to create the function app with bicep and deploy the zip file with "az functionapp deployment" and it works

Comment: Function is also deployed along with the function app? @ValeriaN

Comment: Another option - don't deploy using bicep - split your concerns - Bicep - infra. Pipeline, deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to deploy zip push to a function app with bicep. After a workaround, it appears that there is an issue with `MSDeploy` for zip deployment push. However, if we focus on the error message, it means that the zip file has been corrupted and thus unable to be loaded for the deployment.

I also tried deploying it through bicep by creating a new repository. It was likewise a failure. So, I tried the below approach to meet your requirements.

I created a bicep file for the function app deployment and then used the `AzCLI` command to deploy the function to that specific function app.

`Functionapp.bicep`:

```bash
param functionAppName string = 'func-${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
param storageAccountType string = 'Standard_LRS'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param appInsightsLocation string = resourceGroup().location
param functionWorkerRuntime string = 'node'
@allowed([
  'Windows'
  'Linux'
])
param functionPlanOS string = 'Windows'
param planSku string = 'S1'
var hostingPlanName = functionAppName
var applicationInsightsName = functionAppName
var storageAccountName = '${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}functions'
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-02-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountType
  }
  kind: 'Storage'
}

resource hostingPlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-02-01' = {
  name: hostingPlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    tier: 'Standard'
    name: PlanSku
    family: 'S'
    capacity: 1
  }
  properties: {}
}

resource applicationInsights 'microsoft.insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: applicationInsightsName
  location: appInsightsLocation
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
  }
  kind: 'web'
}
resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    reserved: isReserved
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      alwaysOn: true
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: reference(applicationInsights.id, '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(storageAccount.id, '2019-06-01').keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: functionWorkerRuntime
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION'
          value: '~14'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE'
          value: '0'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*CLI command:*

```bash
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resourcegroup> -n warriorfunc --src Firstrepojahnavi-main.zip
```

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, you can also try uploading the zip file or folder to the blob storage container and once it is uploaded, obtain the container URL from it and paste it in the place of package uri in bicep code as explained in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package).

You can refer here for other [Zip Deployment ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push) if required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried to use the "az functionapp deployment" cli command with the same zip file and it works, that means that in my case the zip file seems to be valid. BTW the creation of a bicep file with only the function app creation and then the use of the az cli to deploy functions doesn't work for my case. I'm trying to automate the deployment of several resources and one of them needs to have the functions created

Comment: If you are trying to push it as a zip deployment, there is an issue with the MsDeploy process. You have to choose some other way as I've given in the above answer until that issue is solved. @ValeriaN